# Is it possible to have mysql transaction without procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, transactions

The problem is to write a transaction statement to update a database column. It could be done inside a procedure where `DECLARE` and `IF` statements can be used. However, the requirement is not to have a procedure. Can this be achieved? Here is what i have tried:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_updatecolumn`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE `_rollback` BOOL DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET `_rollback` = 1;
    START TRANSACTION;
    UPDATE mytable
    SET mycolumn=1
    WHERE mycolumn=2;    
    IF `_rollback` THEN
        ROLLBACK;
    ELSE 
        COMMIT;
    END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Best Regards,

Comment: sure, if you are saying that you don't want to use a stored proc, then don't. Look at error codes that return in the programming language that wraps it

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am running the above code in mysql workbench. the problem is that DECLARE and IF are specific for stored programs. I guess i could use the IF() function instead of the IF statement and SET instead of the first DECLARE. but what about the handler?

Comment: workbench is like mysql command line tools interface. As you say there are whole chunks of constructs that are only for stored programs

Comment: as you say *However, the requirement is not to have a procedure.* ... so it is hard to know what you want from someone

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can rollback the transaction without the procedures, but we can not catch errors in the script (to declare handler) by the script.

We can catch errors after execute sql script and then rollbak or commit:

```
try {
    $pdo->exec("START TRANSACTION;");
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO `test` (`id`) VALUES (:id);');
    $stmt->bindValue(':id', $_POST['id']?$_POST['id']:NULL, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $pdo->exec("COMMIT;");
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    $pdo->exec("ROLLBACK;");
    die("&lt;p>" . $e->getMessage() . "&lt;/p>");
}
```

We can try to do (but it do not work!!!):

```
SELECT @error_count := @@error_count;
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO `test` (`id`) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO `test` (`id`) VALUES (1); -- Error on dupl...
INSERT INTO `test` (`id`) VALUES (3);
-- It is your IF:
SET @sql = (SELECT IF(
    @@session.error_count>@error_count,
    "ROLLBACK;",
    "COMMIT;"
));
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```